# RPC: Segmentation Fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, rpc

Since I stumbled across this problem and there's nothing answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240714/rpc-segmentation-fault-core-dumped), I decided to seek for help for my situation.

I want to make a simple RPC server-client thingy where there are three operations:

- average of an array X[]
- max and min elements of array X[]
- multiplying each element of array X[] with a float number r

so I made my .x file, and generated the skeletons of code for what I need.

```
struct X_arr
{
    int X <100>;
    int X_size;
};

struct max_min
{
    int max;
    int min;
};

struct X_times_r
{
    int X <100>;
    int X_size;
    float r;
};

struct prod
{
    float prod <100>;
};

program DUM_PROG
{
    version DUM_VERS
    {
        float average(X_arr)=1;
        max_min max_and_min(X_arr)=2;
        prod product(X_times_r)=3;
    }=1;
}=0x23451111;
```

Then I fixed the 3 remote procedures for the server and tested my client with a simple hardcoded array, which worked fine (even though I guess there were some `arguments cannot be encoded` error sometimes).

But then I tried to make a menu for a client, asking for the length of X[] and getting the elements for each operation that is needed:

```
...


int i;
int flag=1;
int n;
int r;

int choice;

printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

do
{

    printf("==========================\n");
    printf("=====Dummy Operations=====\n");
    printf("==========================\n");
    printf("1. average of X[] \n");
    printf("2. max & min of X[] \n");
    printf("3. r*X[] \n");
    printf("4. Exit \n");
    printf("==========================\n");
    printf("Choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    printf("==========================\n");




    if(choice==1)
    {
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        //average of X[]
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        printf("Number of elements: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        average_1_arg.X.X_len=n;
        average_1_arg.X_size=n;
        average_1_arg.X.X_val=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("X[%d] = ", i);
            scanf("%d", &average_1_arg.X.X_val[i]);
        }

        result_1=average_1(&average_1_arg, clnt);

        printf("Average of X[]: %.2f\n", *result_1);
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////
    }
    else if(choice==2)
    {
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        //max and min of X[]
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        printf("Number of elements: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        max_and_min_1_arg.X.X_len=n;
        max_and_min_1_arg.X_size=n;
        max_and_min_1_arg.X.X_val=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("X[%d] = ", i);
            scanf("%d", &max_and_min_1_arg.X.X_val[i]);
        }

        result_2=max_and_min_1(&max_and_min_1_arg, clnt);

        printf("Max of X[]: %d\n", result_2->max);
        printf("Min of X[]: %d\n", result_2->min);
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////
    }
    else if(choice==3)
    {
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        //r*X[]
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        printf("Number of elements: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        printf("r: ");
        scanf("%d", &r);

        product_1_arg.X.X_len=n;
        product_1_arg.X_size=n;
        product_1_arg.r=r;
        product_1_arg.X.X_val=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("X[%d] = ", i);
            scanf("%d", &product_1_arg.X.X_val[i]);
        }

        result_3=product_1(&product_1_arg, clnt);

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            printf("%.2f*X[%d]=%.2f\n", product_1_arg.r, i, result_3->prod.prod_val[i]);
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////
    }
    else if(choice==4)
    {
        flag=0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid Choice. Terminating in 3...2...1...\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}while(flag);

printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

...
```

and hell broke loose.
More specifically, a segmentation fault went off at the server, and little time after that, client started to "work" without the connection of the server.

[image]

"Segmentation Fault" gave me an idea of a rogue pointer or an uninitialized variable, but after looking at the code for way too much time, I don't find anything close to that. I suspected the way my `.x` file was written, but I tested a simpler version of it with the same results.

What has gone wrong?

ps: repo for more in depth look of this [here](https://github.com/Coursal/dumrpctest)

**Update:**
I screw around with the procedures at the server, and it seems that almost the entire struct that passes as arguments, doesn't actually pass anything at all, resulting in making a for loop based on garbage.

Comment: "[...] but after looking at the code for way too much time, I don't find anything close to that." This screams "I need a debugger." Looking is fine and all, but a debugger tells you what is actually going on.

Comment: Write an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: if you want to test it from the repo I linked above, simply start `rpcbind` service and then type a `make` before running `./dum_server` and `./dum_client` respectively to two terminals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ah, the walk of shame...*

Turns out I ***left*** all of the default function calls that the generated rpc files hand it to me, ***before*** I made my menu and give my values:

```
result_1 = average_1(&average_1_arg, clnt);
if (result_1 == (float *) NULL) {
clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
}

result_2 = max_and_min_1(&max_and_min_1_arg, clnt);
if (result_2 == (max_min *) NULL) {
clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
}

result_3 = product_1(&product_1_arg, clnt);
if (result_3 == (prod *) NULL) {
    clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
}
```

So everytime the client started, there were already calls for all the functions, with no argument initializations, thanks to the dreadful coding skills of yours truly.

Fixed it and words like a charm. You can test it yourself [here](https://github.com/Coursal/dumrpctest)

[image]